# My Desktop Icons are Magically Moving

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, desktop-icons

I'm tired of the desktop icons moving when I turn on my computer. I've unchecked "Auto-arrange icons" and "Allow themes to change desktop icons" (as suggested by a google search), but the problem persists. Here's a screenshot (I covered the stuff I don't want to share):

[image]

The majority of the icons were on the left side, with the Recycle Bin in the upper left corner. The icons on the left were in the middle and the upper right corner. And so on.

How can I stop Windows from auto-arranging these icons?

---

Some stuff that might help:

I'm using a Dell Theme:

[image]

[image]

But I changed one thing: I added the blank screensaver (The default setting was "none").

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors or change monitors regularly?

Comment: @JasonC No. This is the only one. I could try [not arranging icons to grid](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-to-stop-icons-from-moving-after-reboot-with/b2165125-b23a-4604-8698-c40510176aed), but I do like the grid.

Comment: This normally happens when the resolution changes for some reason, then changes back to the original selection, and example would be when your display drivers are updated.  Why can't you just move the icons back?

Comment: @Ramhound That get's tiring when I have to do it 1 per ~5 reboots.

Comment: FYI, the **Allow themes to change desktop icons** option is unrelated. Was the screen saver triggered at least once before you got the issue? Also, are you able to reproduce it when the screen saver is disabled?

Comment: There are utilities to store your desktop layout information and allow you to restore it with a click if it gets messed up.  I'm not familiar with which ones support Win 8, but it's something to explore.

Comment: I have "solved" this problem by reducing the number of desktop icons. Now they don't move around as drastically, and I don't notice it because there are so few of them. I wonder why reducing the number of desktop icons made this problem almost disappear.